# Multiple Content Pages inside one Tabbed Page

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

I am doing my app from scratch without using TabbedPage template and I really don't know how to put my multiple Content pages inside one TabbedPage. Right now my Tabbed Navigation XAML looks like this:

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
        xmlns:parkingapp="clr-namespace:ParkingApp.Views"
        x:Class="ParkingApp.Tabbed"
        xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
        android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom">
<parkingapp:Profile Title="Profile"></parkingapp:Profile>
<parkingapp:MainPage Title="Parking" ></parkingapp:MainPage>
```

This works fine, I can navigate to Profile and Parking, but inside Parking I have button to navigate to another Content page and once I'm inside that another Content page my Tabbed Navigation bar is not showing and I want it to be shown in all of my Content pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to navigate within a tab, place the contents of that tab inside of a `NavigationPage`.

```
<NavigationPage>
    <x:Arguments>
        <parkingapp:Profile Title="Profile" />
    </x:Arguments>
<NavigationPage>
```

[Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/navigation-tabbedpagewithnavigationpage/)

Comment: Compiler gives me an error: The type 'NavigationPage' does not support direct content. Maybe I should do something in my xaml.cs file?

Comment: Thank you very much, Jason, it worked, although I used PushModalAsync so after your code snippet It still wasn't working so I changed navigation to PushAsync and now it's working fine. Thanks again :)

Comment: @VidmantasTelksnys It seems that Jason's reply help you, please remember to mark it as answer, it is beneficial to others who face the same problem.